# Filter out all keys from Map in Scala except some specific keys

Tags: scala, dictionary, filter

I have a Map in Scala defined as :

```
val x = Map("a"->10, "b"->20, "c"->30, "d"->40)
```

I want to filter out all keys from this map that are not "a" or "c". How do I do this in Scala?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
x.view.filterKeys(Set("a", "c").contains)

// Map(a -> 10, c -> 30)
```

If necessary you can add `.toMap` i.e. `x.view.filterKeys(Set("a", "c").contains).toMap`.

`x.filterKeys(Set("a", "c").contains)` is deprecated.

There is also `x.filter { case k -> v => Set("a", "c").contains(k) }`.